# Next.js Client-side Page Protection/Authentication with useContext() vs. localStorage.getItem()

Tags: reactjs, next.js, local-storage, react-context

There are multiple resources that give examples of how to "protect" pages using useContext() and wrappers in your _app.js file.  These include storing authentication information in the context and wrapping your child components with this context.

_app.js

```
import { AuthProvider } from "../context/AuthContext";

import Layout from "../components/Layout";

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

context/AuthContext.js

```
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";

const AuthContext = createContext();

const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {

  /* -------------------------------------- get our token */

  const [contextVal, setContextVal] = useState({
    currentUser: null,
    token: null,
  });

  // we need to check if a token exists in local storage, and if so, set it
  useEffect(() => {

    setContextVal(() => ({
      currentUser: JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("currentUser")),
      token: JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("token")),
    }));
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ contextVal, setContextVal }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { AuthProvider, AuthContext };
```

protected-page.js

```
import { useContext } from "react";

import { siteTitle } from "../components/Layout";
import { AuthContext } from "../context/AuthContext";

const Homepage = (props) => {

  /* -------------------------------------- check for token */

  // token is on the context defined in AuthContext.js
  const { contextVal, setContextVal } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { token } = contextVal;

  // here is our "protection"
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("signup.js: Running useEffect in signup.js for redirect");
    if (!token) {
      router.push("/");
    }
  }, [token]);


  // use the token to conditionally display elements on the homepage

  /* -------------------------------------- render component */

  return (
    <div className="Homepage">
      <h1>This is the home page!</h1>
      {token ? <h2>User is logged in</h2> : <h2>User is not logged in</h2>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Homepage;
```

Pretty clear and straight forward, EXCEPT, what is a logged in user refreshes the page?

Our current useContext in the wrapper will be cleared, but not localStorage.

This reload triggers our AuthContext to re-intialize with null values and in turn will cause re-rendering of child components, including our protected page. This re-rendering on our protected page will causes a router.push() to occur (even though we were just logged in and viewing the page).

I could be wrong here, but using a bunch of console.logs is seems that the useEffect() in our protected page runs BEFORE our useEffect() in our AuthContext, so naturally there is no token in our context and our user gets re-freshed straight to another page.

Since we cannot place our localStorage calls directly into our initial state (like below) because those will also run on the server side, throwing an undefined error

```
const[state, setState] = useState(() => { localStorage.getItem("token")})
```

we have to wait for an intial render of our app to get the token from localStorage using useEffect() in AuthContext.js. This means that no token exists in our context on the first render...(i'm a newb a not sure why we can't do this).

It seems that this makes for a bad user experience.

**FIX (sort of): Check localStorage from our Protected Page Component Instead of Relying on useContext()**

By doing this, we don't have to wait for AuthContext to update. We can immediately check to see if the token is in localStorage and render the proper elements on our page OR hide them and redirect accordingly. If our token exists in localStorage, the user wouldn't be redirected to another page on a simple refresh!

However, depending on your code in your protected route, this could throw a hydration error.  We would need to refactor our protected-page.js so that the server-side render of the page "matches" the client-side render of the page, and then we can re-render the page on the client side with a useEffect() and change the output.

protected-page.js (refactored with useLocalStorage and to account for hydration)

```
import { useContext } from "react";

import { siteTitle } from "../components/Layout";
import useLocalStorage from "../hooks/useLocalStorage";

const Homepage = (props) => {

  /* -------------------------------------- check for token */

  // token is found in localStorage now
  const [token, setToken] = useLocalStorage("token");
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useLocalStorage("currentUser");

  // here is our "protection", which won't redirect because we'll have our token from localStorage before the useEffect() is run.

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("signup.js: Running useEffect in signup.js for redirect");
    if (!token) {
      router.push("/");
    }
  }, [token]);

  /* -------------------------------------- avoiding hydration issues */

  // the below code avoids hydration issue by keeping the server rendered content
  // the same as the client-rendered content until useEffect() updates our mounted status

  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState();

  // this will run after our page loads in the browser causing another re-render

  useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true);
  }, []);

  // use the token to conditionally display elements on the homepage

  /* -------------------------------------- render component */

  return (
    <div className="Homepage">
      <h1>This is the home page!</h1>

      { mounted ? (
        <>
          {token ? <h2>User is logged in</h2> : <h2>User is not logged in</h2>}
        </>
      ) : null }
    </div>
  );
};

export default Homepage;
```

**1. Finally, what is the point of using useContext() for page protection/authentication?**

**2. Is there a way to avoid the logged-in refresh = redirect issue when using useContext()?**